# AngularJS -directive to self remove/insert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive to control some elements in the DOM, according to the user's permissions. Seeking in the internet, I found the `.remove()` function for the element. It is working nice.

But, if the permissions change, I need to show the DOM element again. How can I do it after calling `.remove()` ?

here is my code:

```
ddo.link = function(scope, el, attrs){

// Validate the permission
if( currentUserService.isAllowed(scope.validatePermission) !== true) {
    el.remove();
}

// Listener for changes
$rootScope.$on("eventName", function(event, param){

    // Validate the permission
    if( currentUserService.isAllowed(scope.validatePermission) !== true) {
        el.remove();
    } else {
        // SHOW THE ELEMENT AGAIN!
    }

});

};
```

Or, is there another way to remove de HTML and insert again? Because with CSS the user can disable through the Developer console...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use ng-if that already does this? If that's a deal breaker, I'd look at the code for ng-if and see how it does it.

Comment: What's the use case where the current user changes so often? Seems like just reloading the currentState when the user changes would suffice as well. I'd be very hesitant to add a listener to the rootScope.

Comment: Mike Feltman thanks for our attention! I need this update possibility, because the permissions are loaded after the Link phasse, so i need to update the exhibition of the directive.

Comment: And I use a directive to concentrate the code in only one place, and not in all controllers...

Answer (score 0):

Instead use `.remove()` try using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` for add a class with `display:none` and remove this when necessary.
The method `.remove()` delete the display element, so you can not show this again.

Another alternative is using `.css()` but your processing is slower compared to others

Comment: But, thiking about Mike comment above, using ng-if is a better choice

Comment: Thanks for your attention Pablo! But with ng-if i will need to insert my code  in all controllers... Am I correct?

Comment: Is there another way to remove de HTML and insert again? Because with CSS the user can disable through the Developer console...

Comment: You can put this in $rootScope. So you are not putting this in all controllers

Comment: For insert and remove HTML you need putting this in a directive, but i think it would very hard. The user can change all via console, not just that html